# What is the academic culture like in Spain for PhD candidates (Work-Life Balance)?

Tags: phd, international-students, work-life-balance, spain

I tried to search for the tags of "Spain" and "PhD" but found nothing.

I'm thinking of maybe doing a PhD in Spain due to ease of access to medical care that would be far more complicated to continue if I had gone to Denmark or Netherlands. Germany is up in the air.

I am currently a Master's Student in Hungary, studying computational modelling of protein/enzyme reactions and structural elucidation using IR, NMR and XRD - so I'm mostly curious about experiences of Physical Chemistry department folk.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you are an international PhD student in the Netherlands or in Denmark you will have access to local medical care. Even in the US, PhD students usually get a decent health insurance.

Comment: @quarague for the US, depends upon the University and State. Some states make their students buy plans on the ACA marketplace.

Comment: @RichardErickson I won't claim it doesn't happen but I think that would be extremely unusual for a funded student in the US to not have health insurance included (but also yes, likely that students are required to have some sort of health insurance which would involve buying insurance if they do not have it from some other source).

Comment: @quarague I am trying to remain vague about what manner of medical care I need due to it being highly politicized.  Retaining the "polite society" approach, I will simply say it is a matter I've made focused effort in getting information from people who have similar needs as me. The primary issue is not affordability, but rather regulation/gatekeeping/restricting access. In this, the U.S would be be superior for some states due to informed consent. Unfortunately, ease of immigration means I'll stick to EU.

Comment: @BryanKrause this varies state-to-state. I'm on a grad committee for a student in Minnesota and that student has a nice university insurance plan.  Conversely, I'm on a committee for a student in South Dakota and their state removed university graduate insurance for students after the passage of the ACA.  It's something someone from outside the US, and, based upon your comments, inside the US would not think of asking about unless they had seen it. Only 48 more states if you like to check for a complete policy check :-)

Comment: @RichardErickson Yikes, that's unfortunate. Yeah, my advice to someone outside the US (or inside the US) applying to a PhD program would be that if they have an offer that does not include health insurance that they should not consider it to be a "funded offer" (though a deduction of some of their stipend to partially cover insurance should be expected).

Comment: My not very wide experience suggests: the group/university will have a mayor impact in the answer of this, academic culture in Spain has more extremes than other places. You'll find the worst and the best withing the country.

Answer (score 3):

If your reason for considering Spain is the free medical care, you should be aware that doctors and medical staff in Spain often do not understand English at all. If you need access to an expert, you should also expect waiting times of at least a few months. In my experience, doctors in Spain are competent, but may lack the equipment necessary to perform tests for diagnosing many conditions.

I have no experience from physical chemistry, but have found academics in my field competent and hard working. The environment may however be soured by the fierce competition for resources. As an example, the University where I worked would prioritize reimbursing the expenses of the students with the most influential supervisors. For the rest, even funding secured through personal grants would be confiscated by the University and it would take them months or years to reimburse expenses, if they were reimbursed at all.

This being said, I believe there may be huge differences between Universities. If you find a group that you would like to join, I recommend asking other international students in the group about their experience.